# CONTAINSTABLE with wildcard works different in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, containstable

I have two same databases one on SQL Server 2005 and one on SQL Server 2008, it have same SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS Collation, and full text search catalogs have the same settings.

These two databases contains table with same data, NTEXT string: 
"...kræve en forklaring fra miljøminister Connie Hedegaard.."

**My problem is:**

CONTAINSTABLE on SQL Server 2008 finds nothing if query is:

```
select * from ContainsTable(SearchIndex_7, Content, N'"miljø*"') ct
```

but SQL Server 2005 works perfectly and finds necessary record.

SQL Server 2008 finds necessary record if query is:

```
select * from ContainsTable(SearchIndex_7, Content, N'"milj*"') ct
```

or

```
select * from ContainsTable(SearchIndex_7, Content, N'"miljøminister"')
```

What can be reason for so strange behavior?

Comment: I just tried it, and all 3 queries work on my instance (SQL 2008).

Comment: Can you publish your db backup?

Answer (score 1):

Check   the default language    in fulltext index column